# JavaScript cancel "mouseleave" event on "click"

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, mouseevent, mouse

I'm working on a problem where I'm not able to find a solution. I'm still a beginner though.
Here the code:

```
var navContact = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-l")[0];
var contactForm = document.getElementsByClassName("kontakt")[0];

var navContactMouseEnter = function (e) {
  console.log("mouse entered!");
  navContact.style.paddingLeft = "5vw";
  contactForm.style.transform = "translateX(-25vw)";
}

var navContactMouseLeave = function (e) {
  console.log("mouse left!");
  navContact.style.paddingLeft = "0vw";
  contactForm.style.transform = "translateX(-31vw)";
}

navContact.addEventListener("mouseenter", navContactMouseEnter, true);
navContact.addEventListener("mouseleave", navContactMouseLeave, true);

navContact.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  navContact.removeEventListener("mouseleave", navContactMouseLeave, true);
  navContact.style.paddingLeft = "5vw";
  contactForm.style.transform = "translateX(0vw)";
});
```

I'm trying to get a little slideIn Animation on "mouseenter" but on "click" that element should slideout completely and **ignore any "mouseleave" event**. There I'm faceing the issues... I'm not able to cancel the "mouseleave" event. That element should only disappear when I click on "X" - but thats no problem.

I'm grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after breaking my head for couple more hours I found out, that I also needed to do this:

navContact.removeEventListener(**"mouseenter"**, navContactMouse**Enter**, true);

I also got different styles on the mouseenter-event, which pulled the element back again.

Lesson learned :D